# Using the select-case statement with cells within ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range, select-case

My idea is to fill the cells on column H depending on what the corresponding cell in the range A:A,D:D,F:F contains.

I'm getting the run-time error 13 (type mismatch) on the line `Case "Done"`, though I'm not sure why, as both the selected range and the variable input are strings. I've always used if-loops, this is the first time I'm using `select case`, but despite having read the reference I still don't know what am I doing wrong.

**The second question** is how to define the last filled row of a range as the end of a new range. Right now with `newRange.Value` I'm attributing a value to the *entire* column, but I'm trying to make sure it only applies to the corresponding cell.

(For clarification, if for example cell A3 contains a value, that means D3 and F3 are empty, so each row in the range A:A,D:D,F:F only contains one value.)

```
Sub setStatus()

Dim dataRange As Range
Dim newRange As Range

Set dataRange = Range("A:A,D:D,F:F")
Set newRange = Range("H:H")

Select Case dataRange.Value

        Case "Done"
            newRange.Value = "Completed"
        Case "WIP"
            newRange.Value = "In Progress"
            'In reality there are many different cases, 
            'hence the select case instead of an if loop
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The value you get from datarange.value is an array (Variant(variant(1 to 1048576, 1 to 1)).  Select case can only accept individual values.  You will need to encapsulate your case statement in a For Each loop that enumerates the values in the dataRange.Value.  You might want to revise the range you are selecting as I suspect you don't really want  to process 1048576 values.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I understand that I can use `lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to get the last row of a column, but I can't find anywhere how I can apply it to a range. Can I use the variable directly (as in `lastRow = Range(dataRange & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`)?

Comment: Maybe try this? : replace "Done" to TRUE. Get the range of cell which has TRUE (special cell, logic) value offset it to H fill with "Completed" value, replace back TRUE to "Done". Using the Select-Case, I think you still need to do the loop. I think Select-Case is not to get all the cells which has value the mentioned Case.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your worksheet with visible row and column headings? Just the top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Application.Match` Applied on Array Instead of `Select Case`

```vb
Sub SetStatus()

    ' Constants
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const DESTINATION_COLUMN As Long = 8
    ' Arrays
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array(1, 4, 6) ' only one column has data
    Dim Cases() As Variant: Cases = VBA.Array( _
        "Done", "WIP")
    Dim Values() As Variant: Values = VBA.Array( _
        "Completed", "In Progress")
    
    ' Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = SOURCE_FIRST_ROW - 1
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count - rOffset
    Set srg = srg.Resize(rCount).Offset(rOffset)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(sCols)
    
    ' Write the matching results to the 1st column of the array.
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cString As String
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim HasDataInRow As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount ' rows of the array
        For c = 0 To cUpper ' given columns of the array
            cString = CStr(Data(r, sCols(c)))
            If Len(cString) > 0 Then
                cIndex = Application.Match(cString, Cases, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    Data(r, 1) = Values(cIndex - 1) ' found in Cases
                Else
                    Data(r, 1) = Empty ' not found in Cases
                End If
                HasDataInRow = True
                Exit For
                'Else ' is blank; do nothing
            End If
        Next c
        If HasDataInRow Then
            HasDataInRow = False
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = Empty ' the row was blank
        End If
    Next r
            
    ' Write the values from the first column of the array
    ' to the destination range.
            
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.Columns(DESTINATION_COLUMN)
            
    drg.Value = Data
      
    MsgBox "Status set.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I’m trying to understand all of the code but I’m having trouble with this snippet:
  `cIndex = Application.Match(cString, Cases, 0)  If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then Data(r, 1) = Values(cIndex - 1)`

If I understood it correctly, `cIndex` returns the relative positions of the cells in row `r` and column `c ` (from the sCols array) that match any of the elements of the Cases[] array.
Why is the second arg in `Data()` a constant 1? Wouldn't then only the first column of the sCols array be valid?

Comment: I'm using the same array and overwriting the first column with the results. In the last line, I'm writing only this resulting column to a single-column range (`Set drg = srg.Columns(DESTINATION_COLUMN)`) i.e. when you have a too big array, only the number of first (left-most) columns equal to the number of columns of the range will be copied. The same goes for rows (top-most, of course) but they are equal in this case.